# scaffold template use cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, t4, scaffolding

When I generate my controller and views with the below command

```
scaffold controller <Entity> -force -repository -DbContextType "XXX" -Area YYY
```

It generates .aspx (web form) pages instead of .cshtml (razor)

How can I change this default behaviour. I think when I first created a new project it asked me to select the default view engine and I picked the wrong one (webforms).

Also are there any free or cheap T4 templates for MVC 3 that generate nicer and more functional views. i.e using webgrid / jQUery etc.

Comment: Perhaps ask: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution wide scaffolders configuration is stored in `scaffolding.config` which is located in the same folder with solution file.

On installation stage `MvcScaffolding` package launches `init.ps` script (you can find it in `<packages folder>\MvcScaffolding.<version>\tools` directory). Script counts `aspx`, `cshtml` and `vbhtml` views and based on these numbers decideds what view scaffolder will be used. Here is a piece of this logic:

```
function InferPreferredViewEngine() {
    # Assume you want Razor except if you already have some ASPX views and no Razor ones
    if ((CountSolutionFilesByExtension aspx) -eq 0) { return "razor" }
    if (((CountSolutionFilesByExtension cshtml) -gt 0) -or ((CountSolutionFilesByExtension vbhtml) -gt 0)) { return "razor" }
    return "aspx"
}

# Infer which view engine you're using based on the files in your project
$viewScaffolder = if ([string](InferPreferredViewEngine) -eq 'aspx') { "MvcScaffolding.AspxView" } else { "MvcScaffolding.RazorView" }
Set-DefaultScaffolder -Name View -Scaffolder $viewScaffolder -SolutionWide -DoNotOverwriteExistingSetting
```

So you can switch view scaffolder using following commands:

```
Set-DefaultScaffolder -Name View -Scaffolder "MvcScaffolding.RazorView" -SolutionWide
Set-DefaultScaffolder -Name View -Scaffolder "MvcScaffolding.AspxView" -SolutionWide
```

Or you can manually edit `scaffolding.config` file and replace value for `ScaffolderName` attribute in tag:

```
<Default DefaultName="View" ScaffolderName="put here either MvcScaffolding.RazorView or MvcScaffolding.AspxView" />
```